# What notions, theorems, proofs connect Free Abelian Groups, $F(n)$, factored by a subgroup with eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, free-abelian-group

Just finished a semester in abstract algebra. We learned about free abelian groups on finite generators and the Smith Normal Form algorithm to find the elementary divisors which describe said free abelian group modded out by a subgroup.

Seeing the Smith Normal Form proof and seeing it in action had me wondering what the idea of an eigenvalue and eigen vector is when the "linear transformation" looking thing is in a ring and not field.

Are there theorems, notions, proofs, etc. that help connect the way we find $F(n)/H$ with the notion of vectors centered at the origin which don't change up to magnitude? Oh and $F(n)$ is the free abelian group on $n$ generator and $H \leq F(n)$ is the factor group for $H$ is a subgroup of $F(n)$

Comment: Do you mean free *abelian* groups ?

Comment: In class we did use the Smith Normal Form computations for factor groups of free abelian groups on n generators. Does this question only make sense when $F(n)$ is a free abelian group?Or does this question also apply to free groups in general?

Comment: Things like matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, linear transformations, and so on, apply **only** to free abelian groups. Free groups themselves do have a very different theory of "transformations" though.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the post to specify free abelian groups. I will also look the the theory of "transformations" for free groups